# What Minecraft resources are impossible or difficult to obtain in peaceful?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to find a definitive list of resources (from both the overworld and nether), that are 100% impossible to obtain in peaceful mode in a vanilla survival game without using any cheats.

Furthermore, what resources become (very) difficult but not impossible to obtain in this situation?

Comment: There is a mod called Extra Utilities that among other things offers a 'Peaceful Table'. This item allows you to get the items you would normally only get from mobs on peacefull difficulties. Just some FYI

Comment: You can always try the [Peaceful Pack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1094417-152-162-all-wuppys-mods-updated-14-8-13-get-the-peacefulpack-thaumcraft-addon-for-15-now/#PP), which was originally made for that purpose.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since the only items impossible to obtain in peaceful are mob drops (that are not obtained otherwise) **and derivatives**, here's a list of unobtainable items:

- Blaze rod
- Music discs (with the exception of music discs "13" and "cat")
- Ender pearls (even though you can obtain an eye of ender by trading)
- Spider eye
- Ghast tear
- Slimeballs
- Magma cream
- Nether star
- Wither skeleton skull

There are only a handful of direct derivatives:

- Brewing stand (requires Blaze Rod)

  - This leads to no potions as well, especially those that use a Fermented Spider Eye, Ghast Tear, Blaze Powder, or Magma Cream
- Sticky Piston (requires Slimeball)
- Beacon (requires Nether Star)
- The Wither (requires 3 Wither Skeleton Skulls, but you're not going to spawn that on peaceful anyway)
- Fire Charge (requires Blaze Powder)

  - Also limits available Fireworks

And here is the list of drops you can still obtain:

- Bone (can be found in temple and dungeon chests)
- Rotten flesh (before snapshot 12w22a could be traded with villagers but can also be found in temple and dungeon chests)
- Strings (obtained by: destroying cobwebs and tripwires and it has 53% chance of spawning in a dungeon chest)
- Arrows (can be crafted with other resources available in peaceful, can be found in temples and can be traded with villagers)
- Gunpowder (will be possible to loot in dungeon chests)
- Gold nuggets (can be obtained by placing a gold ingot into a crafting area)
- Dragon egg (reaching the end is possible by trading eyes of ender with villagers; apparently the ender dragon won't despawn on peaceful and the creation of a piston is still possible)
- Glowstone dust (can be obviously obtained in the nether and by trading with villagers)

It is also to note that a lot of items, that are possible to obtain, won't be renewable anymore, like:

- Bone (previously farmed by killing skeletons or wither skeletons)
- Coal (**not charcoal**, previously farmed by killing the wither skeleton)
- Gunpowder (previously farmed by killing creepers, ghasts or witches)
- Strings (previously farmed by killing spiders and cave spiders)

Comment: Is gold renewable on peaceful?  Or iron?  Zombie Pigmen may still spawn, so you would be able to farm them for gold, but how is iron renewable without Zombies?

Comment: @MBraedley, ehm. Iron golem farms?

Comment: Touche.  Forgot about that.

Comment: redstone is still renewable, it can be purchased from villagers.

Comment: In recent versions of minecraft, villagers no longer trade eyes of ender, and instead trade ender pearls.

Comment: Strings are still a renewable resource as they are dropped by Striders. All potions are inaccessible apart from the thick and mundane potions (which have no effect, I don't know why they're in the game) and instant health potions, as they can be found in End ships. Sticky pistons can still be obtained as they generate in jungle temples.

Answer (score 0):

The things I think of immediately:

- ghast tears
- blaze rods
- wither skeleton skulls
- ender pearls
- spider eyes
- slimeballs
- magma cream

Other mob drops are craftable/findable in dungeon chests.
Carrots and potatoes will require you to find a village that has some planted.

Comment: I think you can find bonemeal in dungeons, so they probably fall into the "difficult to obtain category". Other resources I can think of off the top of my head include Slimes (and therefor sticky pistons), Magma Cream.

Comment: Incorrect. Zombie flesh and bones (and bonemeal) can be obtained by temple/dungeon chests.

Comment: Yes you can definitely find gunpowder in chests in dungeons and abandoned mineshafts.